# Composite data can't be refreshed

Tags: silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

I use EF+WCF Ria Service for a SL app.Suppose I have 2 tables Person, PersonPhone.  2 entities will created by EF.

Then defined PersonPhone as composite in meta data for WCF ria service like:

```
   [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Person.PersonMetadata))]
    public partial class Person
    {
        internal sealed class PersonMetadata
        {
            private PersonMetadata()
            {
            }

            [Include]
            [Composition]
            public EntityCollection<PersohPhone> PersonPhone { get; set; }

           //......
     }
}
```

then define a wcf ria service method as:

```
 public IQueryable<Person> GetPersonByID(int id)
        {
            var result = this.ObjectContext.Persons.Include("PersonPhone")
                .Where(x => x.PersonID == id);               
            return result;
        }
```

then call this method in SL app like:

```
  Context.Load<T>(Context.GetPersonByIDQuery(id), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, r =>
            {
              //......
            }, null);
```

Problem is:First time to call, it is okay, all PersonPhone is loaded.

For testing purpose, I remove some of data from PersonPone in SL app, but not save it back to DB, like:

```
Person.PersonPhone.Remove(personphone);
```

Or:

```
   Person.PersonPhone.Detach(personphone);
```

then Call the method to load Person again in SL app, Person.PersonPhone is not refreshed.

How to resolve this problem?